# Executing programatically composed SQL within Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, jdbc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am working on an existing codebase that uses Spring Boot - and all that goes with it, to build a simple RESTful API atop a MySQL database.

I need to programatically compose and then execute a SQL query. The `@Query` annotation is the closest I've found, but that doesn't allow for runtime SQL composition.

TL;DR - Oh! What I wouldn't do for a simple JDBC Query interface.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [JPA Criteria Queries](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-criteria-queries) and [JOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/).